# How to parse a data with dynamic set of fields?

Tags: java

What approach shall I take if I would need to parse an incoming data with a dynamic set of fields. I can request a `List` of these fields though, so I know the amount of fields and their names at runtime. I don't know how to construct a `model` which I would use to parse the data and use afterwards. Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you please give more context about your application? Is the set of possible attributes fixed? How should you deal with missing fields?

Comment: The set of possible attributes is not fixed. After data is parsed I shall display it, the only fields which came.

Comment: A simple bean with 2 properties (attr name, and attr value) would be good. Then a couple of business classes enumerating the composition. But beware of the "perfect lookup sindrome".

Comment: @BigMike, what business classes you mean?

Comment: since you know the names, I suspect that you can enumerate 'em. For example: a list rappresents a financial transaction, so it's a collection of attribute/value pairs. In a class Transaction (or better in an interface), you can have the constants for attributes name and even a Set/Collection of valid attr names, with method for validating the list and to some extent, even read only getter with meaningfull names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with the attribute name/ attribute value pair within a javabean, but, in order to keep track, I'd also add some business class (or interface) enumerating the allowed value for attributes.

Let the code speak:

```
class MyBean {
  String name;
  Object value;

  // Getters and setters
}
```

Now, if one of those list rappresents a dog, we may have a class like:

```
class Dog {
   private List<MyBean> dataSet;

   // Enumerate the possible values of MyBean.name for a valid Dog object
   public final static String KIND = "kind";
   public final static String AGE = "age";
   public final static String BARFES = "heBarf";

   // Use a convenience Set for checks
   public static Set<String> validAttributes;

   // Put valid values in the convenience set once for all
   static {
     // trivial code to initialize the validAttributes set 
   }

   // We won't add setters, better constructing a new object every time
   public Dog(List<MyBean> v) {
      dataSet = v; // better copying ? as usual it depends on scenarios. 
   }

   // A convenience static to parse a string into this object.
   public static Dog parse(String theStream) {
      // cannot write since I don't know how is format, but this method can use the enumerations of the attribute names for checking. 
   }

   // Accessor
   public int getAge() {
      return dataSet.get(Dog.AGE);
   }

}
```

Well possibilities are infinite. You can have a base class (a List) and use it as a base class for business classes (adding just getters and proper constructor) or use a List as a private data member (remember to keep it hidden - don't give a direct access to its reference).

You can probably go with some enum too. The important thing, in using this kind of meta-datas (because in the end these are metadatas) is keeping track of valid names (there's no compile checks, so you need to have some sort of quick and dirt way to monitor things).

PS: Don't mind code, is actually just a proof of concept (probably won't even compile).

Answer (score 0):

Though your question is is not clear, I will try to answer. If you know the field names then you will have to do as it is done on command line, supply parameter and retrieve their value.
If you know the delimiter, then parsing is easy. For complex data structure you can construct the syntax with regular expression to parse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Another easy way:

1) parse the dynamic List as a JSON string in a for loop, OR make a map instead of list with the key as field name and value as field value.

2) convert the JSON string or map with any [JSON lib](http://www.json.org/).